# Why is a # getting added to url when click on autocomplete result?

Tags: jquery

The below code does what i want but then everytime i click on a autocomplate value which has been fetched from database the value does gets added inside the input field but then in the page url say index.php# a hash gets added.

how can that be prevented could someone get me a solution?

Here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#from-input").keyup(function () {
    let searchText = $(this).val();
    if (searchText != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "airports.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
          query: searchText,
        },
        success: function (response) {
          $("#from-show-list").html(response);
        },
      });
    } else {
      $("#from-show-list").html("");
    }
    });
    // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
   $(document).on("click", "#from-show-list a", function() {
        $("#from-input").val($(this).text());
        $("#from-show-list").html("");
    });
  });
  
  
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#to-input").keyup(function () {
    let searchText = $(this).val();
    if (searchText != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "airports.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
          query: searchText,
        },
        success: function (response) {
          $("#to-show-list").html(response);
        },
      });
    } else {
      $("#to-show-list").html("");
    }
    });
    // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
  $(document).on("click", "#to-show-list a", function() {
        $("#to-input").val($(this).text());
        $("#to-show-list").html("");
    });
  });
```

here is the html

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <label class="form-label-outside">Origin</label>
                        <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-modern">
                          <input id="from-input" class="form-input" name="from" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Airport/City Name">
                         <div id="from-show-list" class="list-group" style="z-index: 9999; position:absolute; max-height: 200px;  overflow: auto;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <label class="form-label-outside">Destination</label>
                         <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-modern">
                         <input id="to-input" class="form-input"  name="to" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Airport/City Name">
                        <div id="to-show-list" class="list-group" style="z-index: 9999; position:absolute; max-height: 200px;  overflow: auto;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Show your HTML as well.. are you using <a href="#"> to execute the function?

Comment: @Professorval updated it

Comment: this is the php if ($result) {
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-1">'.$row['cityName'].' ('.$row['code'].') - <small>'.$row['name'].'</small></a>';
      }
    } else {
      echo '<p class="list-group-item  border-1">Airport not listed!</p>';
    }
  }

Comment: ok i added onclick="return false" and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'href = "#"' part of your PHP code and it won't show up anytime you click it again.

The the JavaScript function will run, nonetheless!